# Extending from Suite Runner vs BlockJUnit4Runner while defining some TestRules

Tags: java, interface, junit, junit-runner, junit-rule

I have a requirement to write many tests. I have extended Suite Runner of JUnit in order to be able to add new annotations where I can mention several Prerequisite classes which will be executed before any of the tests or setups get executed. My Typical test looks like this.

```
@RunWith(CustomSuiteRunner.class)
@BeforeSuite(Prerequisite.class)
@AfterSuite(CleanupOperations.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
                SimpleTests.class,
                WeatherTests.class
            })
public class SimpleSuite {
}
```

I have overridden `public void run(final RunNotifier notifier)` to add code the required code to trigger prerequisites and cleanup operations mentioned in BeforeSuite and AfterSuite annotation.

Now, I'm trying to find out how I can achieve the same by extending `BlockJUnit4Runner`?  I can't find any method equivalent to run that starts the execution to override the behaviour. There is runChild which gets triggered before a child gets executed.

The reason I'm looking for this is I'm trying created several rules in an Interface and make my tests implement that so that they will be available, however as Interface elements are static and final JUnit is ignoring these. In another Question I asked today I got answer that I can make JUnit consider rules mentioned in an Interface by extending BlockJUnit4Runner and overriding `getTestRules()`.

So, Here is what I'm trying find out.

1. Is it possible to extend BlockJUnit4Runner to make it take a list of tests and run them as suite and also run some code before any tests get execute and after all tests are executed?
2. How can I extend Suite Runner to consider TestRules defined in an implemented interface?

Comment: We extend BlockJUnit4Runner to override createTest() where we customize the instances.
We use org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(Runner) to run the classes. We have also customized the the Runner to repeated run the tests... So its very well doable.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty much possible to extend BlockJUnit4Runner and make it take a list of tests and run them as suite with required test dependencies handled within the extended runChild() method

```
public class CustomRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
  private List<String> testsToRun = Arrays.asList(new String[] { “sample1” });

  public CustomRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
  }

  public void runChild(FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
    //Handle any dependency logic by creating a customlistener registering notifier
    super.runChild(method,notifier);

  }
}
```